# JOptionPane not displaying all items from ArrayList

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying to write a program that will create a food order consisting of food items displayed from a menu. Each item is selected and given a certain quantity. I want to display the items that I select in a JTextField but it has not been working correctly.

There are a few problems that I have ran into and cannot seem to figure out,

1. The JOptionPane is supposed to display all of the items that I added to the deli arraylist, but it only displays the first one which is Nachos.
2. My getTotalPrice method is not properly calculating the cost and I'm not entirely sure why.
3. I want the program to determine if an item is already present in the Arraylist and add to the quantity if it does, and if not then add a new entry to the arraylist. However, it always adds a new item, regardless of if it exists already.

The following is my are all of my class files.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu {

private final ArrayList<Item> menu;

public Menu() {
    menu = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    menu.add(item);
}

public Item getItem(int itemNo) {
    if (menu.size() > itemNo) {
        return menu.get(itemNo);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        return String.format("%s: %s \n",i+1, menu.get(i));
    }
    return null;
    }
}

public class Item {

private final String name;
private final double price;

public Item(String name, double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Name %s @ Price $%s", name, price);
}

public boolean equals(Item item) {
    return item.name.equals(item.name);
}

}


public class ItemQty {

private final Item item;
private final int quantity;

public ItemQty(Item item, int quantity) {
    this.item = item;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s - %s\n", quantity, item);
}

public boolean equals(ItemQty itemQty) {
    return itemQty.getItem().equals(itemQty.getItem());
}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Order {

private final ArrayList<ItemQty> order;

public Order() {
    order = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addToOrder(ItemQty itemQty) {
    if (order.contains(itemQty)) {
        int amount = itemQty.getQuantity();
        amount += 1;
    }
    else
        order.add(itemQty);
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    for (int index = 0; index < order.size(); index++) {
        double price = order.get(index).getItem().getPrice();
        int quantity = order.get(index).getQuantity();
        double sum = price * quantity;

        return sum;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < order.size(); index++) {
        str += order.get(index).toString() + "\n\n";
    }
    return str;
}
}
```

Any help or critiques would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> My getTotalPrice method is not properly calculating the cost and I'm not entirely sure why.

This is due to the fact that you're returning the value of `sum` only after the first iteration of your loop

```
public double getTotalPrice() {
    for (int index = 0; index < order.size(); index++) {
        double price = order.get(index).getItem().getPrice();
        int quantity = order.get(index).getQuantity();
        double sum = price * quantity;

        return sum;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Something like...

```
public double getTotalPrice() {
        double sum = 0;
    for (Order item : order) {
        double price = item.getItem().getPrice();
        int quantity = item.getQuantity();
        sum += (price * quantity);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

would work better

> The JOptionPane is supposed to display all of the items that I added to the deli arraylist, but it only displays the first one which is Nachos.

Since there is no `JOptionPane` in your code, it's impossible to know what the issue might be

> I want the program to determine if an item is already present in the Arraylist and add to the quantity if it does, and if not then add a new entry to the arraylist. However, it always adds a new item, regardless of if it exists already.

Okay, this is a lot more difficult, because you code doesn't really provide enough support to do it.

There's no way for your code to update the quantity information after the `ItemQty` is created, you will need to supply a setter of some kind to perform this action (or a `add` method, to which you pass another `ItemQty` and it does the job for you)

First, I'd add a new method to `ItemQty`

```
public class ItemQty {
    //...
    public void add(int quantity) {
        this.quantity += quantity;
    }
}
```

This just makes it possible to increase the quantity.

Second, I'd change the `Order#addToOrder`, I'd make it so you had to pass an `Item` and a `quantity` to it (other classes don't need to make a `ItemQty` object in this case).  In this method, I'd search for a matching item and either update it or add it to the order.

```
public class Order {

    //...

    public void addToOrder(Item item, int quantity) {
        List<ItemQty> matches = order.stream().filter((itemQty) -> {
            return itemQty.getItem().equals(item);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (matches.size() > 0) {
            matches.get(0).add(quantity);
        } else {
            order.add(new ItemQty(item, quantity));
        }
    }
```

Okay, that might have you scratching your head, it does me, but basically, it's just a fancy pancy way for saying...

```
public void addToOrder(Item item, int quantity) {
    ItemQty match = null;
    for (ItemQty check : order) {
        if (check.getItem().equals(item)) {
            match = check;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match != null) {
        match.add(quantity);
    } else {
        order.add(new ItemQty(item, quantity));
    }
}
```